# Get list of projects with its process Name

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying get all the projects with its process name. I tried to use the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 which lists all projects without process name.

I know that we can get process of each project with its capabilities set to true. But with this approach i need to hit the api equal to total number of projects.

I want to avoid this and get details of project with its process with minimal api hits, may be a single api hit. Is there a way to get both easily?

Comment: You can't only with one API hit, but what is the issue to loop the projects?

Comment: So if you have 200 projects and go for looping, we need to hit the API 200 times!!!! I think ADO should have a better way to do this as process of project is basic detail, Microsoft should have provided this data with "list of projects API"

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such REST API to do it. But you could do it by calling

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_settings/projects?__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

And the projects' results are in *fps > dataProviders > data > ms.vss-admin-web.organization-projects-data-provider > Projects* (include process template name).

This is the request of Organization Settings > Projects page. ([https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_settings/projects](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D/_settings/projects))

Comment: Is there a way that I do this using azure devops .NET client libraries?

Comment: @ARUNVARRIAR Based on my test, the process template info isn't in ProjectHttpClient.GetProjects() and ICommonStructureService.ListAllProjects() of Azure DevOps .NET Client libraries. So, the simple way is calling https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_settings/projects?__rt=fps&__ver=2 and the result content type is json.

Comment: @ARUNVARRIAR What's the result after you trying it by calling https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_settings/projects?__rt=fps&__ver=2? Do you have any other questions?